# Adding drag & drop to a datagrid column in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have two datagrid components and I would like to drag one column from one component to the other. I have been trying several methods but I couldnt acomplish that.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: This page gives the code and a working SWF of drag and drop enabled data grids http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/19/dragging-rows-between-two-different-flex-datagrid-controls/ But that's for dragging rows (the data) - I don't think you can drag a column from one datagrid to another.

Comment: you can drag the column within the datagrid - to move its location from being the first column to the second and so on. But you are trying to drag columns between different datagrids, right?

Comment: I already have seen that site. It explain how to drag and drop rows. I want to drag and drop the column between differente datagrids.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to disable a column on the first datagrid and enable it on the second. You have to listen to DRAG_START events, find what field is the target column, and hide it on the first datagrid when the drag succeeds. Then you use a symetrical approach for the second datagrid...

I guess you will have to create a custom drag proxy visual component if you want it to be visually coherent.

Good luck =)

Comment: I'm trying to do something like that. I have added this property to advancedDataGrid component (dragStart="dragStart(event)" ) and created this function:
public function dragStart(event:MouseEvent):{
  var column:AdvancedDataGridColumn=event.target.parent.data;
  var dragSource:DragSource = new DragSource();
  dragSource.addData(column,'advancedDataGridColumn');
  DragManager.doDrag(column, dragSource, event);
}

My first problems is the function is not being called and the other problem I get an error in the last line of the function.
can't do conversion AdvancedDataGridColumn to IUIComponent